# Return receipt from gmail, yahoo etc. from lotus notes (lotusscript)

Tags: lotusscript

I am sending mails using lotusscript to gmail, Yahoo, hotmail etc. I want to get return receipt from the user & build a report:

1. Who opened the mail
2. Who did not receive the mail
3. Non-existent address
4. Inbox full
5. Blocked
6. Has user clicked on the link sent
7. Opt out
8. Bounced emails

Is it possible to get these details from mails sent to gmail, yahoo.
Can we achieve this in xpages (SSJS/ CSJS)

Answer (score 0):

Points 1+2: Return receipts require that the receiving client honours the request. So you will need to check the clients you plan to target.

Gmail for example will only give this feature for the business version.

Points 3,4,5,8 would normally be automated mails returned from the system. Again this is dependent on the systems you are talking to.

Points 6,7 would be within the mail client.

You would need to pull that data from multiple sources. You can then create an XPage to report this, but it is not something you can do with a code snippet from here.

Comment: Thanks Simon for your reference.